# Deduce P(h|h or w) from P(h), P(w), P(h and w) and P(h or w)

Tags: probability

Life expectancy tables for a given couple predict that the husband has a 60% chance of surviving 10 years and his wife has a 80% chance of surviving 10 years.
1.) Find the probability that both survive 10 years.
2.) Find the probability that ONLY ONE of the couple will survive 10 years. 
3.) Given that only one survives after 10 years, what is the probability that it is the husband?

My solution:

1.) P(Husband and Wife survive) = 0.48

2.) P(only one of them survive) = 0.92

3.) P(Husband survives given that husband or Wife survives) = 0.65

Edit: Wrote the whole problem.

Comment: Applying the definition P(h|h or w)=P(h and (h or w))/P(h or w)=P(h)/P(h or w), perhaps?

Comment: Note that if you were only given P(h) and P(w) and "deduced" from these the values of P(h and w) and P(h or w) given in your post, then this deduction is wrong and there is no way to compute P(h|h or w).

Comment: Was it given that h and w are independent? If not, where do you get P(h and w)? More info needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this formula:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
which here means:
$$P(h|h\ or\ w)=\frac{P(h\ and\ (h\ or \ w))}{P(h\ or\ w)}=\frac{P(h)}{P(h\ or\ w)}=\frac{0.6}{0.92}$$

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider
   $$(A\ and \ B) \equiv (A \cap B)$$
   and
   $$(A\ or \ B) \equiv (A \cup B)$$
2. This is [Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)
   $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\ and \ B)}{P(B)}$$
3. And This is always true that  $$h \subset (h\ or\ w)$$ so
   $$P\Big((h)\ and\ (h\ or\ w)\Big) = P(h)$$
   This means if $A$ be a subset of $B$ then [Intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection) of $A$, $B$ is $A$.
4. Solution
   $$ 
   \begin{align}
   P(h|h\ or\ w) &= \frac{P\Big((h)\ and\ (h\ or\ w)\Big)}{P(h\ or\ w)}\\
   \\
   &= \frac{P(h)}{P(h\ or\ w)}\\
   \\
   &=\frac{0.6}{0.92}\\
   \\
   & \simeq 0.65
   \end{align}
   $$